# How to back up two internal hard drives using Time Machine?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, ssd, external-disk

I upgraded my macbook pro and have now two internal SSD drives (I removed the old drive and also the DVD drive).

I have been using Time Machine to back up the 1st drive to an external drive, and I now wonder **if there is any way I can also use Time Machine to back up the new second SSD drive**.

Hope it makes sense..

so I back up my main SSD-1 drive to an external drive called Backup1.

and now would like to back up my second drive called SSD-2 to a second drive called Backup2.

Is it possible to use Time Machine for that?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot do this with Time Machine unfortunately.

What you can actually do is backup both internal SSD drives to the same external drives - or backup both internal SSD drives to two different external drives.

However, you cannot setup it up so that SSD #1 only is backed up to external drive #1, and SSD #2 only to external drive #2.

Answer (score 1):

It can back up two drives, but Time Machine will only back up **to one drive**, and stores the backups as images.
You probably be better off in this instance with Carbon Copy Cloner, a more granular set up is possible there.

Comment: Actually Time Machine can backup to two drives from Sierra and newer. However, you cannot select different exclude lists for the two drives.